# Problem by accepting follower request with a secured twitter account - Twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

My Twitter application is based on a **secured** twitter account and should be able to accept or deny follower requests. At the moment I query new incoming friendship request through `twitterInstance.getIncomingFriendships(-1);`
which works fine.

Now I want to accept a request. For this purpose I use `twitterInstance.createFriendship(friendId);` and my application will tell my account to follow this person **but** this function does not "accept" his following request.

What is wrong with this approach? Is there another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've learned that this is impossible.  I posted an answer to a related question here: [How do I use the Twitter API to approve a follower request for a protected account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996761/how-do-i-use-the-twitter-api-to-approve-a-follower-request-for-a-protected-accou/9023484#9023484)