# How do I use the Twitter API to approve a follower request for a protected account?

Tags: api, twitter

The [friendships/create](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/friendships/create) seems to be the closest option, but their documentation doesn't explicitly mention this case.  Has anyone been able to accomplish this?

Comment: I have not tried this yet, but I've gotten an official Twitter response.  Posting it as the answer now.

Comment: Hmm. You can only use the API permissions that your own account has access to after auth. But this is an interesting edge case because your creating a new follow.

Answer (score 2):

I got an official response from a Twitter employee.  He says:

> It's not technically possible on the platform today because there is
>   no Twitter API call to approve a follow request to a protected
>   account.

So that's that.